# REQUEST_URI htaccess nginx

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, apache2

htaccess to nginx rewrite convertion help

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} apiv01
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

I want when access uri GET http://localhost/hospital_project/apiv01/listHospital/3211 can display

```
    {"header":{"code":"401","message":"wrong token"}}
```

I've used the configuration of anilcetin like this:

```
location /hospital_project {
if ($uri ~ "apiv01"){
        set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
        }
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /hospital_project/api.php?params=$1;
        }

}
```

Also i've used the configuration of https://winginx.com/en/htaccess like this:

```
location /hospital_project {
  rewrite apiv01 /hospital_project/api.php?params=$1;
}
```

But when i access http://localhost/hospital_project/apiv01/listHospital/3211 the output is equal to http://localhost/hospital_project/apiv01 (no effect)

Normal if i using http://localhost/hospital_project/api.php?params=apiv01/listHospital/3211

--- Edit
also i use

location /hospital_project/apiv01 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /hospital_project/api.php?params=$request_uri;
}
but also no effect

this solve with using reverse proxy to apache2 like this

```
location /hospital_project {

proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
}
```

but im still curious if using rewrite in nginx

Answer (score 1):

nginx implements front-controller patterns in a simpler and more effective way than Apache. The nginx way looks like this in your case:

```
location ~ ^/(hospital_project/apiv01.+)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /hospital_project/api.php?params=$1;
}
```

You only add this location on the top of the nginx configuration. You don't need to use `if` or `rewrite` directives at all.

Comment: The OP suggests this doesn't work. `$request_uri` (Nginx) is a bit different to the captured backreference (`$1`) in the Apache `.htaccess` file. (Notably, `$request_uri` contains the slash prefix and any URL params, whereas `$1` does not.) Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: hi, thanx for reply. but this does not work

Comment: Please, do not just tell "this does not work". It doesn't help at all in figuring out why it would not work. Provide concrete details of HTTP request, access log entries, what exactly happens etc.

Comment: I changed the `location` block to use regex, which captures the part after `/` to `$1` variable, therefore the slash is ignored. However, using regex matching here might affect behaviour of other `location` blocks.

Answer (score -1):

sorry, mean i use;

```
location /hospital_project/ {
  rewrite apiv01 /hospital_project/api.php?params=$1;
}
```

but no effect

also i use

```
location /hospital_project/apiv01 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /hospital_project/api.php?params=$request_uri;
}
```

but also no effect

this solve with using reverse proxy to apache2 like this

```
    location /hospital_project {

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
```

but im still curious if using rewrite in nginx

Comment: If the code in the other answer did not work for you then you should _comment_ on the other answer, instead of including that information in another "answer" - otherwise, no one will be notified of your reply. If you have more information to add to your question then please _edit_ your question. (It doesn't look like you would need to proxy the request?)

Comment: dear, sorry for that. I have edited it